# GCD in iOS always creating new threads

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have many codes like this:

> dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{});

`dispatch_async` will create a new thread when I call it one time.
When app run a while， I got many threads: number 50, 60, 70. It's not good.
How to reuse those threads. Like `tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`

This is my code. It's need do some image stitching things after download, then save.

```
- (void)sdImageWith:(NSString *)urlString saveIn:(NSString *)savePath completion:(completionSuccess)successCompletion failure:(completionFalse)failureCompletion {

    [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:SDWebImageDownloaderUseNSURLCache progress:nil completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error, BOOL finished) {

        if (data.length <= 100 || error != nil) { failureCompletion(error); return;}

        dispatch_async(imageStitch, ^{
            NSLog(@"thread：%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
            [[DLStitchingWarper  shareSingleton] StitchingImage:data savePath:savePath];
            if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savePath]) {
                successCompletion(savePath);
            }else {
                NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"x" xxxcode:404 userInfo:nil];
                failureCompletion(error);
            }
        });
    }]; 
}
```

Comment: Why isn't that good? And why do you think to know better than GCD? "Sleeping" threads don't waste anything. They are reused, when GCD decides so.

Comment: A queue isn't equal to a thread, forget about the thread in gcd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dispatch_get_global_queue` doesn't necessarily create new threads. It will pull threads from a limited pool of "worker" threads that GCD manages for you. When it's done running your dispatched task, it will return this thread back to the pool of worker threads.

When you dispatch something to a GCD queue, it will grab an available worker thread from this pool. You have no assurances as to which one it uses from one invocation to the next. But you simply don't need to worry about whether it's a different thread, as GCD is managing this pool of threads to ensure that threads are not created and destroyed unnecessarily. It's one of the main reasons we use GCD instead of doing our own `NSThread` programming. It's a lot more efficient.

The only thing you need to worry about is the degree of concurrency that you employ in your app so that you don't exhaust this pool of worker threads (having unintended impact on other background tasks that might be drawing on the same pool of worker threads).

The most draconian way of limiting the degree of concurrency is to employ a shared serial queue that you create yourself. That means that only one thing will run on that serial queue at a time. (Note, even in this situation you don't have assurances that it will use the same thread every time; only that you'll only be using one background worker thread at a time.)

A slightly more refined way to constrain the degree of concurrency in your app is to use `NSOperationQueue` (a layer above GCD) and set its `maxConcurrentOperationCount`. With this, you can constrain the degree of concurrency to something greater than 1, but still small enough to not exhaust the worker threads. E.g. for network queues, it's not unusual to specify a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 4 or 5.

---

In your revised question, you show us a code snippet. So, a couple of thoughts:

1. Don't worry about what `[NSThread currentThread]`. GCD will manage the threads for you.
2. Is this stitching process slow and potentially using a fair degree of memory?

   If so, I would not suggest either a serial queue (only allowing one at a time might be too constraining), nor a global queue (because you could have enough of these running concurrently that you'd use up all the available worker threads), nor a GCD concurrent queue (again, the degree of concurrency is unbound), but instead use an `NSOperationQueue` with some reasonable limited degree of concurrency:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue *stitchQueue;
   ```

   And

   ```
   self.stitchQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
   self.stitchQueue.name = @"com.domain.app.stitch";
   self.stitchQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4;
   ```

   And

   ```
   - (void)sdImageWith:(NSString *)urlString saveIn:(NSString *)savePath completion:(completionSuccess)successCompletion failure:(completionFalse)failureCompletion {

       [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:SDWebImageDownloaderUseNSURLCache progress:nil completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error, BOOL finished) {
           if (data.length <= 100 || error != nil) { failureCompletion(error); return;}

           [self.stitchQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
               // NSLog(@"thread：%@", [NSThread currentThread]); // stop worrying about `NSThread`
               [[DLStitchingWarper  shareSingleton] StitchingImage:data savePath:savePath];
               if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savePath]) {
                   successCompletion(savePath);
               }else {
                   NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"x" xxxcode:404 userInfo:nil];
                   failureCompletion(error);
               }
           }];
       }];
   }
   ```

If you prefer to use a custom GCD serial queue (with only one stitching operation possible at a time) or a custom GCD concurrent queue (with no limit as to how many stitching tasks running at any given time), feel free. You know how time consuming and/or resource intensive these operations are, so only you can make that call. But operation queues offer the benefits of concurrency, but simple control over the degree of concurrency.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rob.  BTW: Base on this code, If I need GCD's dispatch_group_notify method, download two images and stitch them.Then I have no choose, only custom GCD serial queue?

Comment: Nope, you can use `dispatch_group_notify` with operations, too (though obviously the final task would have to run on a GCD queue). Or you can use operation dependencies (create a completion operation that is dependent upon all of the other operations).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `dispatch_get_global_queue`, use `dispatch_queue_create` and save a reference to the queue. Reuse it like any other instance variable.

Comment: I made some changed: dispatch_queue_create("com.imageStitch", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT); 
But still get new thread.

Comment: @ChokWah Yes, creating a new queue will create at least one new thread. The idea is to reuse that same queue instead of creating a new queue every time. Since you posted so little information in your question it is difficult to provide and further suggestions.

Comment: I worry about creating such a new queue, and the application will crash because there are too many threads.

Comment: You are not reading my answer. Create the queue just one time. That's it. Reuse it over and over. If you want more help, post more details about how you are using the queue in your question.

Comment: I dont think he ONLY needs a separate queue. though you are right he should have one but he needs to control what he adds to it!?

Comment: Hi , man. I update I question , may be help you all understand what  I need.

Answer (score 2):

the default implementation to concurrent queue does reuse threads but doesnt wait for free threads: if none are free, itll create.

it will thus overcommit and you need to assure you dont spawn too many long running tasks yourself. For a 'real' thread pool

You need 
a) your own queue(s)
b) a 'limiter' so that you

for an example see : [IOS thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812161/ios-thread-pool)